# Magento2 : Disable Pagination on certain condition from Category Page

Tags: magento2.2.2, product-list, pagination

I want to disable pagination and per page product which display on category page on some condition i.e. if I set cookies than on category page I want to disable pagination from category page otherwise it will show.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override **Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml**
using your custom module.

in that file magento display toolbar using below code

```
<?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
```

do your stuff over there.

Comment: There is already toolbar present on category page. I just want to display all product on category page when my cookie is set.Currently it show pagination for load more product.Is this possible??

Comment: you need to code that that

Comment: Can you please guide me how can I achieve this.